# ADFS Certificate expiration notification job

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, system-administration, adfs4.0, rpt

I have over 20 applications utilizing ADFS SSO authentication.  Last year the token signing certificate expired and I went through the whole sky is falling - chasing down 3rd party vendors to schedule the refreshing of the metadata files to try to make the transition to the new cert as seamless as possible.  I have already added calendar reminders 3+ months before their next expiration but I would like to be a little bit more prepared and have a job/script that runs and send me an email when the certificate is 90+ days from expiration.  Does anyone know of or have a script that could do accomplish that?  Also, is there a way I could do the same per RPT signature certs?  I currently have most if not all set to automatically update but would like the notification anyway if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few around e.g. [this](https://github.com/natescherer/Get-ExpiringAdfsCertificate).

"This script will query AD FS certificates (via Get-AdfsCertficate) and Relying Party Trust certificates (via Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust) and check if the certificates expire within a user-defined threshold (or the default 30 days if not specified). It will then output details about expiring certificates, and, optionally, send an alert email."